# Unable to install SSMS with Azure Data Studio 18.9.1 - getting fatal error

Tags: sql-server, installation, ssms, fatal-error

I am trying to install Sql Server Management Studio with Azure Data Studio 18.9.1, but I always get error as below in screenshot:

[image: SSMS 18.9.1 Installation Error]

Also, I am logged-in as an administrator on my Windows 10 Pro laptop, so I don't understand that this is an admin access issue.
Please help me rectify the error and install SSMS successfully. I have googled the error but I unable to solve this issue. I reinstalled my VS2019 full setup with modify and repair options but still I am unable to install SSMS 18.9.1.

In the log file this message is there:
"mainviewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: Fatal error during installation (0x80070643)"

Comment: So when you click on the link that says `Click here for the log file` what does the log file say happened? Do you have anti-virus software "helping" you by scanning that folder while you're trying to install files into it? Since Windows Vista UAC and privilege separation have been a thing - when you launch the setup program do you right-click on it and select `Run as Administrator` to get a proper Administrator token?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I updated the ques with log file error msg..

Comment: Right click on SSMS an execute "Run as Administrator"

Comment: @Max already tried that many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to resolve my issue by uninstalling anti virus (Symantec End Point Protection). First, I turned off the anti virus but still the issue was not resolved. Finally, I uninstalled my anti virus and then I was able to install SSMS 18.9.1